# Vista hangs during installation on VMWare

Tags: windows-vista, vmware-workstation

I am installing Windows Vista Business x86 (no Service Pack) on VMWare Workstation 10.01, but it never completes the final step (translated it is probably the step "Completing installation...").

[image: Screenshot]

I let it run for more than 4 hours, which is usually far more than needed to install an operating system.

Some more information:

- The dots are still moving, so it's not frozen
- It freezes (dots are not moving) when I install it with VMWare's EasyInstall feature.
- I'm using the default VMWare settings for Vista to install
- I'm installing from an ISO file which is located on a NAS
- The VM has assigned 1 GB RAM and 1 processor with 2 cores
- The hard disk (40 GB) was partitioned by me in advance (1 block, maximum size)
- There is enough hard disk space for the virtual hard disk to expand
- My host system is i5, 16 GB RAM, Windows 7 x64, almost fresh installation (3 days old).

**What could cause the installation to hang and what could I try make it install?**

It's not getting better if I try

- a local copy of the ISO
- disconnecting the network during installation
- letting Vista auto-partition the hard disk

It worked fine with my copy of Windows Vista Home Premium x86 Service Pack 1.

Comment: Are you installing from an ISO, or an actual disk?  Did you partition and/or format the (virtual) disks ahead of time, or did you let the Vista installer create them?  How much RAM did you assign to the VM?

Comment: @techie007: Added the information. ISO mounted from a NAS. Partitioned in advance (but using the installer). 1 GB RAM. 1 processor, 2 cores.

Comment: Try removing all partitions and letting the installer make them from scratch.  After that you'll want to try a Vista disk with SP1 (or later) slipstreamed onto it.

Comment: I totally agree that you'll have better results if you try to use a Vista disk with service pack(s) preinstalled... ideally SP2. If the problem persists, use your support request with VMware to put in a request about this.

Comment: @techie007: I let Vista create the partitions, used a local copy of the ISO and disconnected the network (just to make sure it's not downloading updates or similar). Still not better.

Comment: Yeah, then I'd say use a Vista disk with a SP on it. I've run into it a few times where the SP0 Vista just doesn't seem to like the hardware. My guess is that SP1 and later introduce more/better drivers.

Comment: The Home Premium ISO also includes the Business Edition. Use this ISO to install Vista Business (Insert the Business key or skip the key and select the Business Edition)

Comment: @magicandre1981: There's no such option during installation. Maybe that's because it is a system builder (OEM) version.

Comment: @ThomasW. don't use the EasySetup feature of VMware!